# Java EE servlet to create a file and show progress while creating it

Tags: ajax, file, servlets, jakarta-ee

I need to write a servlet that will return to the user a csv that holds some statistics.
I know how to return just the file, but how can I do it while showing a progress bar of the file creation process?

I am having trouble understanding how can I do something ajaxy to show the progress of the file creation, while creating the file at the same time - if I create a servlet that will return the completion percentage, how can it keep the same file it is creating while returning a response every x seconds to the browser to show the progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two fundamentally different approaches. One is true asynchronous delivery using an approach such as Comet. You can see some descriptions in articles such as [this.](http://blogs.oracle.com/carolmcdonald/entry/a_comet_slideshow_example_using) I would use this approach where the data your are delivering is naturally incremental - for example live measurements from instrumentation. Some Java App Servers have nice integration between their JMS message systems and comet to the browser.

The other approach is that you have a polling mechanism. The JavaScript in the browser makes periodic calls to the server to get status (and maybe the next chunk of data). The advantage of this approach is that you are using a very standard programming model, less new stuff to learn. For many cases, such as "are there new answers for the Stack Overflow question I'm  working on?" this is quite sufficient.

Your challenge may be to determine any useful progress information. How would you know how far through the generation of the CSV file you are?

If you are firing off a long running request from a servlet it's quite likely that you will effectivley spin off a worker thread to do that work. (Maybe using JMS, maybe using asynch workers) and immediately return a response to the browser saying "Understood, I'm thinking". This ensures that you are not vulnerable to and Http response timeouts. The problem then is how to determine the current progress. Unless the "worker" doing the work has some way to communicate its partial progress you have nothing useful to say. This kind of thing tend to be very application-specific. Some tasks very naturally have progress points (consider printing we know how many pages to do and how many printed) others don't (consider determining if a number is prime - yes or no, no useful intermediate stages perhaps)